# Spacing issues with xspace

Tags: latex, spacing, xspace

Let's say my macro is `\newcommand{\k}{king\xspace}`. Then the spacings in
"... said the \k." will be fine. But what do I do if I want no spacing in the
middle of \k\k.? I want "kingking." not "king king."

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this should go on tex.SE... it doesn't seem to be about the programming aspects of LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

`\unskip` removes any previous skip inserted (which includes a space), so using `\K\unskip\K` for the odd occasions when you want to remove it could also suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\newcommand{\K}{king\xspace}
\begin{document}
Here is the \K. Here is the \K\K. Here is the \K\unskip\K.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of `\xspace` is to add a space between words and not add space before punctuation. So, if you don't want spaces between the two uses of the macro don't use `\xspace`.  But, of course this will require you to you to use a `{}` at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\K}{king}%

\begin{document}
At end of sentence \K.\par
In between \K\K{} you want one long word.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The xspace documentation says that the way to handle this is with {} immediately after your macro invocation:

```
 \k{}\k
```

Recent versions of xspace also permit you to specify additional macros that should not generate space after your macro:

```
 \xspaceaddexceptions{\k}
```

I wanted to use this for \xspaceaddexceptions{\textsuperscript}, but it didn't work for me since my shop has xspace v1.06 and that's not recent enough.  So I used:

```
 \newcommand{\unix}{\textsc{unix}\xspace}
 \unix{}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
```

Which worked fine except in bold section headings, since there's no bold small caps in the font that I'm using.  Sigh...